# What triggers Shulk's alternate counter?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

As seen in Shulk's trailer, Shulk's counter (Vision) has two attacks to it. But, when I use it, the first one is the one that shows up. How do I trigger the second one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you hold the analog stick in the direction the attack is coming from as it connects while Shulk is in his counter stance, Shulk will use his faster dash counter.

Comment: Do you mean "tilt" as in the same style used in tilt moves?

Comment: Just hold the analog stick in the direction of the incoming attack until you pull off the counter. I don't know the exact terminology.

Comment: (Tilt is the term for moving the stick up a slight bit, example: an up tilt is moving the stick up a bit, but not enough to jump, then pressing A).

Comment: @ShadowZ. Ah, in that case, it doesn't matter how much you move the stick while Shulk is performing his counter move, so long as you move it before the incoming attack hits.

Comment: Tested it out again, I realized that it is much harder to pull off than what I expected.

Comment: You also have to be on the ground